# Axis Custom Handler not being run for wsdl

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, axis

We have a legacy web service using Axis 1.4 to receive SOAP calls. Currently the servlet-mapping in the web.xml is using the url-pattern `/services/*` so that anything under `services` will map to the AxisServlet. Our wsdd file looks something like this:

```
<deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java"> 

 <service name="MyService" provider="java:RPC">
  <parameter name="allowedMethods" value="*"/>
  <parameter name="className" value="com.foo.MyService"/>
  <wsdlFile>path/to/wsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
 </service>

 <transport name="http">
  <requestFlow>
   <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper"/>
   <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.HTTPAuthHandler"/>
  </requestFlow>
 </transport>

 <globalConfiguration>
  <requestFlow>
   <handler type="java:com.foo.AxisRequestHandler"/>
  </requestFlow>
  <responseFlow>
   <handler type="java:com.foo.AxisResponseHandler"/>
  </responseFlow>
 </globalConfiguration>

</deployment>
```

We now no longer want everything under `services` to go to Axis, only `services/MyService` so that we can use other technologies for other requests under `services`.

So, I changed the web.xml url-pattern for thew AxisServlet to `services/MyService`. Then, I wanted to remove the URLMapper from the wsdd and have my `AxisRequestHandler` send all requests to `MyService`. So, the wsdd now looks like this:

```
<deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java"> 

 <service name="MyService" provider="java:RPC">
  <parameter name="allowedMethods" value="*"/>
  <parameter name="className" value="com.foo.MyService"/>
  <wsdlFile>path/to/wsdl.wsdl</wsdlFile>
 </service>

 <transport name="http">
  <requestFlow>
   <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.HTTPAuthHandler"/>
  </requestFlow>
 </transport>

 <globalConfiguration>
  <requestFlow>
   <handler type="java:com.foo.AxisRequestHandler"/>
  </requestFlow>
  <responseFlow>
   <handler type="java:com.foo.AxisResponseHandler"/>
  </responseFlow>
 </globalConfiguration>

</deployment>
```

And in the `AxisRequestHandler` I have this:

```
public void invoke(MessageContext context) throws AxisFault
{
    context.setTargetService("MyService");
}
```

This all works great when actually making the SOAP calls. However, when I go to `/services/MyService?wsdl` to server up the WSDL file, I get the following error:

[image: error]

I've put debug logs in the `AxisRequestHandler`, and whenever I hit the wsdl, it never hits my handler. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging through the Axis code a while, I found that there is a `generateWSDL` method for the handlers. I added this to `AxisRequestHandler`:

```
public void generateWSDL(MessageContext context) throws AxisFault
{
    context.setTargetService("MyService");
}
```

This method gets called when hitting `/services/MyService?wsdl` , causing the right service to be set.